# Disable / uncheck checkbox in GridView (DevExpress)

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, checkbox, devexpress

Is there any way to programmatically uncheck or disable row's checkbox (just for a few, based on condition) in DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView?
GridView is binded with BindingSource. If you need any other informations, just ask. I recieve a project with DevExpress but no experience with it so sorry if my question is silly.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: For uncheck you can use `SetRowCellValue` and set `false` to the corresponding column

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks, this works but if I want to change it in event it doesn't. CellValueChanged event doesn't fire if I (un)check checkbox and CellValueChanging event fires, however it still check checkbox. I need to prevent checking some checkboxes.

Comment: Are you sure [CellValueChanged event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CellValueChangedtopic) should fire when you call `SetRowCellValue`. Otherwise I'll suggest you to get help from vendor..

Comment: Why not "directly" set the corresponding property in the underlying object instance and refresh the view with view.RefreshData()?

Comment: Why not remove the checkbox from the cell based on some condition, then you would not need to worry about people checking/unchecking the checkbox

Comment: @RyanGunn I've already solved it but thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution I've found.

```
private void GridView_ShowingEditor(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (<some condition>)
        e.Cancel = true;

}
```

More info [here.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A249)